# notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't refresh my view

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm doing this in an AsyncTask, everything working fine but my view is not directly refreshed,

but if i just scroll a bit on  my listView the data are refreshed

```
 ArrayList<Project> listProject =  taskLiteApplication.getListProjectWithStatus(Integer.parseInt(status[0]));


            //set adapter
            projectBaseAdapter.replaceData(listProject);

            //display projects on screen
            projectBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I try to call refreshDrawableState() on my listView and it doesn't work as well
and invalidate() too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any UI updates from an AsyncTask should be done in the `onPreExecute` and the `onPostExecute` methods of the AsyncTask class.

So in your case, after your AsyncTask is complete, you want to update the UI. Therefore you should override the `onPostExecute` method of your AsyncTask , and in that method call `projectBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`